# enable camera locally in a multiplayer game usin Photon PUN 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

In my multiplayer game, I want to have a spectator camera called "Up Camera" that would be enabled when any player dies.

It is enabled when a player dies, but it is enabled for all players such that even if you haven't died, it will use the camera as though you were the one who died.

The variables are being transmitted by the projectile that contains the IDs of the player who shot the bullet and the player that the bullet collided with.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Pun;
public class damageMenager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int hp;
    public GameObject player;
    public Image hpBar;
    public PlayerSpawner playerSpawner;


    public void Update()
    {
        if(this.gameObject == player)
        {
            hpBar.fillAmount = hp / 100f ;

        }


    }
    private void Awake()
    {
        playerSpawner = FindObjectOfType<PlayerSpawner>();
    }

    public void takeDamage(int damage, GameObject otherPlayer, int shooterId)
    {
        if (otherPlayer.GetPhotonView() != null)
        {
            if (otherPlayer.GetPhotonView().ViewID != shooterId)
            {
                if (hp <= 0)
                {


                    foreach (Transform tm in otherPlayer.transform)
                    {
                        if (tm.GetComponent<wheelController>() != null)
                        {
                            tm.GetComponent<wheelController>().enabled = false;

                        }

                    }

                    otherPlayer.transform.Find("Camera").gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    otherPlayer.transform.Find("CM FreeLook1").gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    otherPlayer.transform.Find("Canvas").gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    otherPlayer.GetComponent<tuttiPU>().enabled = false;
                    otherPlayer.GetComponent<mina>().enabled = false;
                    otherPlayer.GetComponent<Inpiedi>().enabled = false;
                    otherPlayer.GetComponent<cannoniDavanti>().enabled = false;
                    otherPlayer.GetComponent<localPlayerManager>().enabled = false;
                    otherPlayer.GetComponent<damageMenager>().enabled = false;
                    otherPlayer.transform.Find("Up Camera").gameObject.SetActive(true);

                }
                else
                {
                    hp -= damage;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

When this player kills another, the camera switches to the the dead player.

I need a suggestion to just enable the "Up Camera" locally on the player whose life is less than 0.

Comment: `otherPlayer.XYZ` instead of any of those you rather want to call a method on this accordin player -> this method would trigger an RPC only to the according client -> only on that according client do all those things ... what object is this `damageMenager` attached to? is it on your player?

Comment: as a general comment: there shouldn't be an `if - else` case at all .. what if you do `hp -= damage;` and now it is `<= 0` ? ;) .. => you should rather always do `hp -= damage;` and then have a check `if(hp <= 0)`

Comment: @derHugo is correct, the `otherPlayer` variable is not the other client, it is your copy of them.  Send them an RPC and they can enable their camera.

Comment: 1. Could you provide an example of what you said

2. yes the damageMenager is attavhed to the player

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**

Providing an example as you requested is always difficult without having all details.

I will still try to point out here what is generally the issue in your concept and how to go about it - this code will most probably not work as a copy&paste solution though. I rather hope you understand the concept and can then adopt it into your project.

---

#### The issue

As mentioned one main misconcept/misunderstanding in your code is that `otherPlayer` at this point has absolutely nothing to do with networking at all. You are colliding with an object local on your device and call certain methods on it such as enabling the camera => This happens on your local device!

The fact that it also happens on all other clients is only due to all other clients executing the same thing locally as well!

#### The solution

So what you rather would want to do - you mentioned this `damageMenager` is a component on your player - is only handle the `takeDamage` on your local client => it should be an RPC that other clients send to you whenever thy want to call it.

Then this taking damage should only be handled by you and you only activate your own local camera.

So assuming this `takeDamge` is called by something that is actually hitting your player (e.g. another players bullet) it should probably rather look like e.g.

```
// As this is on the player make it a MonoBehaviourPun so you have access to your PhotonView
// additionally in order to synchronize the HP field make it an IPunObservable and implement OnPhotonSerializeView (see below)
public class damageMenager : MonoBehaviourPun,  IPunObservable
{
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public int hp = 100;
    public Image hpBar;

    [Tooltip("Add all your own components that should be disabled when you die")]
    public List<Component> ThingsToDisableOnDeath;
    [Tooltip("Add all your own GameObject's that should be deactivated when you die")]
    public List<GameObject> ThingsToDeactivateOnDeath;
    [Tooltip("Add all your own GameObject's that should be activated when you die")]
    public List<GameObject> ThingsToActivateOnDeath;

    private void Awake()
    {
        playerSpawner = FindObjectOfType<PlayerSpawner>();
        hpBar.fillAmount = hp / 100f;
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void takeDamage(int damage)
    {
        // make sure only handled by local client
        if(!phtonView.IsMine) return;

        hp -= damage;

        hpBar.fillAmount = hp / 100f;

        if (hp <= 0)
        {
            // if you already reference those in ThingsToDisableOnDeath as well you can skip this
            foreach (var wheel in GetComponentInChildren<wheelController>())
            {
                wheel.enabled = false;
            }

            foreach (var component in ThingsToDisableOnDeath)
            {
                component.enabled = false;
            }

            foreach (var obj in ThingsToDeactivateOnDeath)
            {
                component.SetActive(false);
            }

            foreach (var obj in ThingsToActivateOnDeath)
            {
                component.SetActive = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // And now to the synchronization of the HP field
    public void OnPhotonSerializeView (PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        
        if (stream.isWriting) // basically means you are the local client 
        {
            stream.SendNext(hp);
        }
        else // you are another client receiving the information
        {
            hp = (int)stream.ReceiveNext();

            hpBar.fillAmount = hp / 100f;
        }
    }
}
```

and instead of the other thing directly calling

```
otherPlayer.GetComponent<damageMenager>().takeDamage(damageAmount);
```

it should rather go through (no photon expert so not 100% sure)

```
var damageManeger = otherPlayer.GetComponent<damageMenager>();
damageManeger.photonView.RPC(nameof(damageManeger.takeDamage, damageManeger.photonView.Owner, damageAmount));
```